# C - Can an if statment change a value of a variable

Tags: c

For example:

```
if(mvwinch(win,y,x=(oldx-1))=='X')
```

Is the value of the variable 'x' now changed?

Comment: Would `if(++x)` change x? Yes.

Comment: Please don't write code like this.

Comment: ["Side Effects"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) are almost always bad. My personal recommendation is to not use them even if the effect is intentional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before comparison, both expressions will be evaluated and any side effect could take place during the evaluation. So, yes `x` would be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, Let me demonstrate with a simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a=5;
    int x=3;
    int c=10;
    if((c=(x>5)?20:30))
    //Do nothing
    printf("value of c = %d",c);

}
```

The output of the program is

```
value of c = 30
```

Which means the ternary opeartor inside the **if** condition has worked assigning new values to the variable **c** (*assigns new value 30*). which explained by [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'mvwinch'. It should work after making that change.